# I have installed Apache server on Windows server 2019 and am trying to restrict phpMyAdmin from access outside of server

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have installed Apache. php and MariaDB  on Windows server 2019. No xampp, wamp or any other platform installer. What I am trying to do is restrict opening of phpmyadim from out side of the server while allowing accessto the LMS. PhpMyAdmin along with a production LMS site are located in the htdocs folder. Currently the LMS is open on the local area network as is phpmyadmin. I am assuming changes will have to be made in httpd-vhosts.conf file but having no luck. In previous install I have used xampp.

Answer (score 0):

To set it up as a alias which is normal I think, in httpd.conf add an include like

```
Include "C:/folder_above_DocumentRoot_for_security/alias/phpMyAdmin.conf"
```

Then the conf file looks like

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/Wherever/YouInstalled/phpmyadmin/"

<Directory "c:/Wherever/YouInstalled/phpmyadmin/">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Require local
</Directory>
```